# Refresh a page in JQM, then fire pageinit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following set up:

`Page1` has:

**Update**

- **Update: `input type="date"` (set to today on page init)**
- a button that links to anther page (`Page2`) with a list view
- a div that get update depending on what user selected from the list
  view page

`Page2` has:

- list view of bunch of links.

When a user clicks a link of `Page2` it checks if the selection is valid depending on the date on `Page1`. if yes then it goes back to `Page1` and updates a `div` with bunch of info about the selection. If the selection wasnt valid it brings up a dialog box with a message and a `Start Over` button.

This all works fine except what i would like to do is when the user clicks `Start Over` reload  and redirect to `Page1`

This is how i do that:

```
<input type="button" class="reload" value="Start Over" />
$('.reload').live( "click", function()
{
    $.mobile.changePage( "#Page1", {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true,
        changeHash: true,
        reloadPage: true
    });
});
```

This works however once the page is reloaded it doesn't call `pageinit`

```
$('#Page1').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  setTodaysDate();
});
```

and therefore the date isn't displayed on `Page1`

The page needs to be reloaded because i have to rest the `div` so it doesn't show any info about the precious successful selection. Any idea how i could accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `$('#Page1').on('pageshow', ...);` instead?

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion but i only need to set the date on Start Over action. I just realized my question is written wrong... the date isnt a a label rather a datepicker. So if i would user pageshow i would lose the users selection when the navigate back from page 2

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following code on page 1,

```
$(document)
  .unbind("pageshow.initializedate")
  .bind("pageshow.initializedate",
    function(event){
      setTodaysDate();
    }
  );
```

Note that page initialization events (e.g. pageinit) will only fire once per "page" as opposed to the show/hide events, which fire every time a page is shown and hidden. Note that in jQuery mobile, pages are loaded through ajax and cached by default. Once per page means that it will fire only on first load of the page, and once the page is cached and displayed again, the page initialization events are no longer executed.